# How do I use mouse event listeners outside of the document class?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, addeventlistener

Sorry if this is a newbie question but: how do I use mouse event listeners outside of my document class. I have the following simplified document class:

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    public var realMain:State1 = new State1();

    public function Main():void 
    {
        addChild(realMain);

        //stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
    }

    /*
    *private function handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
    *{
    *   trace("Main");
    *}
    */
}
```

and I want to be able to use the same stage.addEventListener functionality commented above in this class:

```
public class State1 extends Sprite
{

    public function State1() 
    {
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
    }

    private function handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        trace("State1");
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work in its current state; "State1" isn't outputted. I have seen references to the use of the Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE event, but am not sure if that is what I need to do, or how to use it. Again, I'm sorry if it has been answered before, I may have seen the question and the answer before but I just am not very good at understanding what is an answer to my questions in as3 yet.

Answer (score 2):

Your `State1` is blank so it can't take any mouse events. Try drawing something there and see how it works.

```
public function State1()
{
    var g:Graphics = graphics;
    g.beginFill(0);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    g.endFill();

    addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
}
```

If you just want a blank object, then just draw a transparent rectangle there (pass `0` as second argument to `beginFill()`).